# Having an issue with my switch menu in a while loop

Tags: c++

So I am working on a switch inside of a while loop. And it is not behaving properly. When I select 'l' and load the file it lets me select again, then when I try and press 'p' to print it, it just keeps looping over the selection prompt. I am pretty sure it is because choice != 'q', but don't know how to fix it.

Thank you for any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
//create a struct called Weather
struct Weather {
    int month;
    int date;
    int high;
    int avg;
    int low;
    double precip;
    string event;
};
//function prototypes
int loadData(ifstream &file, Weather days[1000]);
void printData(Weather days[1000], int count);

int main() {    
    // declare variables
    Weather days[1000];
    ifstream inFile;
    string checker;
    char choice = '0';
    int month = 0, count;
    string path;

    cout << "Welcome to the weather analyzer!" << endl;


    while (choice != 'q') {
        cout << "Would you like to (l)oad data, (p)rint data, (s)earch data, (o)rder the data, or (q)uit? ";
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;

        switch (choice) {
        case 'l':
            // promt user for file path
            cout << "Please enter the file path: ";
            cin >> path;
            // open the file
            inFile.open(path);
            // checks to see if file successfully opened and terminates if not
            if (!inFile) {
                cout << "Bad Path";
                getchar();
                getchar();
                return 0;
            }
            loadData(inFile, days);
            count = loadData(inFile, days);
            break;
        case 'p':
            printData(days, count);
            break;
        case 's':

        case 'o':

        case 'q':
            cout << "Good bye!";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option";
        }

    }

    // Close file.
    inFile.close();

    // Pause and exit.
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

//loading function
int loadData(ifstream &inFile, Weather days[1000]) {
    string checker;
    int month = 0;
    int i; //i varaiable keeps track of how many lines there are for the print function
    for (i = 0; !inFile.eof(); i++) {
        inFile >> days[i].date; // gets date and checks if it is 2017 with if loop
        if (days[i].date == 2017) {
            getline(inFile, checker);
            getline(inFile, checker);
            inFile >> days[i].date; //gets correct date value
            month++;//increments month counter
        }
        days[i].month = month;//gets and stores data from file into days
        inFile >> days[i].high
            >> days[i].avg
            >> days[i].low
            >> days[i].precip;
        getline(inFile, days[i].event);

    }
    return i; //returns amount of days 
}
// printing function
void printData(Weather days[1000], int count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << days[i].month << " "
            << days[i].date << " "
            << days[i].high << " "
            << days[i].avg << " "
            << days[i].low << " "
            << days[i].precip << " "
            << days[i].event << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `loadData` twice?

Comment: And while it's not an error to call `loadData` twice, think about the effects that will happen if you do.  While you're at it, get and learn to use a decent debugger.  The answer will jump off the page at you within a couple of minutes if you single step through this in a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the user input with `cin`, you probably want to flush the `cin` buffer:

```
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(INT_MAX);
```